# Advantage of 64-bit MSBuild?

Tags: .net, msbuild, 64-bit

Other than not being able to build Silverlight, can anyone tell me what the differences are between  32 and 64 bit MSBuild? All I can find on Google are articles about 64-bit builds, but 32-bit MSBuild seems to be able to build x64 assemblies just fine.

Comment: Ginormous solutions, building a managed operating system for example.  Maybe, I seriously doubt it.  Troubleshooting the file system redirection problems won't be fun, no doubt the cause for the Silverlight build problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 64 bit version will have access to more address space.  There is a writeup of it here that also covers some disadvantages: [Is there any advantage to building my .NET application with the 64 bit framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733975/is-there-any-advantage-to-building-my-net-application-with-the-64-bit-framework)

Answer (score 1):

32-bit MSBuild seems to be able to build x64 assemblies just fine - this is correct.

++ more address space - needed for a huge builds

-- issues with using assemblies forced to 32/64bit - 64bit aspnet_compiler is called from 64bit MSBuild and I faced with forced 32bit reference issues.