# Which MSBuild (x86 vs x64) to use when building for AnyCPU platform?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, msbuild, msbuild-4.0

I'm using a batch file to call MSBuild which builds a solution file. My question is that when building for AnyCPU platform, which MSBuild should I use? the 32bit or 64bit one?

```
set sln=MySolution.sln
set src=%CD%\..\
set msbuildx86=%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe
set msbuildx64=%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe

set verbosity=/v:normal

%msbuildx86% "%src%%sln%" %verbosity% /t:Clean;Build /p:NoWarn=1591 /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="Any CPU" <-- x86 or x64?
%msbuildx86% "%src%%sln%" %verbosity% /t:Clean;Build /p:NoWarn=1591 /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="x86"
%msbuildx64% "%src%%sln%" %verbosity% /t:Clean;Build /p:NoWarn=1591 /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="x64"

%msbuildx86% "%src%%sln%" %verbosity% /t:Clean;Build /p:NoWarn=1591 /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform="Any CPU" <-- x86 or x64?
%msbuildx86% "%src%%sln%" %verbosity% /t:Clean;Build /p:NoWarn=1591 /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform="x86"
%msbuildx64% "%src%%sln%" %verbosity% /t:Clean;Build /p:NoWarn=1591 /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform="x64"
```

Comment: It is irrelevant.  Just as irrelevant as the platform name.  The only thing that matters for managed code is the jitter forcing, the one you set in the IDE's Project + Properties, Build tab.  You should always use the msbuild.exe that your IDE uses.  Which is not the one you are trying to use.  Use the Visual Studio Command Prompt, type "where msbuild.exe".

Comment: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0>where msbuild.exe
 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe
 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\MSBuild.exe`
Don't I need the 64bit MSBuild to build for 64bit platform?

Comment: thank you, found my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8617054/advantage-of-64-bit-msbuild

Answer (score 0):

When building for x86, using the x86 compiler is faster and slightly more stable. Most users who wanted the 64bit tools generally wanted a larger working memory for large application. You can set PreferredToolArchitecture=x64 as environment variables and MSBuild will pick them up.